# Fourier transform of $\sin(2t)\exp(-3|t|)$ by convolution property

Tags: fourier-transform

Hello and thanks for reading.

I have the next problem, which must solve with convolution property of Fourier transform.

Let be $f(t)=\sin(2t)\exp(-3|t|)$, and I meet the next Fourier transforms;

If $g(t)=\exp(-3|t|)$, so $\hat{g}(\omega)=\frac{6}{9+\omega^2}$
And

If $h(t)=\sin{2t}$, so $\hat{h}(\omega)=-i\pi(\delta(\omega-+2)-\delta(\omega-2))$

The answer is $\frac{-24i\omega}{\omega^4+10\omega+169}$, I got it with the definition.

The definition that we use in class is:

$\hat{f}(\omega)=\int^\infty_{-\infty}f(t)\exp{(-i\omega t)}dt$

The problem is correct multiply by Dirac delta out an integral?
If the answer is yes, how I can it?

Comment: it is not a **multiplication** by a $\delta$ but a **convolution** by a _shifted_ $\delta$. Don't use an integral, but apply plainly the following rule $\delta(\omega-a)\star f(\omega)=f(\omega-a)$, do it in the same way with the other $\delta$ and then take inverse Fourier.

Comment: Any comment on my comment ?